# Function definition like range

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

Suppose I wanted to write a function similar to [range](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

Recall that range has a one argument and 2/3 argument form:

```
class range(object)
 |  range(stop) -> range object
 |  range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object
```

If I wanted the method or function to have the same interface, is there a more elegant way than this:

```
def range_like(*args):
    start,stop,step=[None]*3
    if len(args)==1:
        stop=args[0]
    elif len(args)==2:
        start,stop=args
    elif len(args)==3:
        start,stop,step=args
    else:
        raise ValueError       
    print(start,stop,step)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not much to suggest here, but one alternative could be using optional arguments and swapping the first two if only one were provided:

```
def range_like(start, stop=None, step=1):
    if stop is None:
        start, stop = 0, start
    ...
```

Comment: I did not give the downvote, but both of your answers do have an issue if `None` is a valid argument.  Consider `slice()` which accepts similar arguments, `slice(1)` needs to be equivalent to `slice(None, 1, None)`, but `slice(1, None)` needs to equivalent to `slice(1, None, None)`.

Comment: in that case you can use sentinel objects.  but using None as a missing argument marker is standard python practice.

Answer (score 4):

i would write this as:

```
def range_like(start=None, stop=None, step=1):
    if stop is None:
        start, stop = stop, start
    ...
```

if that does what you want?

[update] you can also add:

```
    if stop is start is None:
        raise ValueError()
```

also, to use sentinel objects instead of None (this isn't normal in Python, but you see it sometimes):

```
NOTSET = object()
def range_like(start=NOTSET, stop=NOTSET, step=1):
    if stop is NOTSET:
        start, stop = stop, start
```

which allows `None` as an argument.

Comment: why did this get two downvotes?  other people have since posted almost identical answers.  what are we all doing wrong?  if you downvoted, please explain why.

Comment: It should be more explicit that the first argument is not optional. If  you use `def range_like(start, stop=None, step=1)` instead, calling `range_like()` will result in a more useful error message.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make an optional argument appear before mandatory arguments.

You can devise workarounds like swapping arguments:

```
def range_like(s, t=None, u=None):
    if t is None: 
        s,t = t,s
```